# How to format date using php to query Google Calendar feed?

Tags: php, javascript, date, google-calendar-api

I have an events feed that needs the dates in this format.

```
query.setMinimumStartTime("2011-12-15");
query.setMaximumStartTime("2011-12-19");
```

When I pull from the database `<?php $startmin = $line['StartDate'];?>`
it comes in this format "12/15/2011"

I use `<?php $fstartmax = str_replace('/','-',$startmax);?>`
to change the "/" to "-" and now have `12-15-2011`

how can I make it `2011-12-15`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime('12/15/2011');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$date->add($interval);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php & https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php for more info.

Comment: I also need to increment 1 to the day is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I updated my post, take a look at the documentation if you want to know more.

Comment: I just noticed that just adding one day wouldn't help my problem since the day could be the 31st of the month and if I were to add one day it would just become the 32nd.... now I am trying to add this "T23:00:00.000-00:00" onto the query so it retrieves events until 11pm that night.

Comment: Don't worry if you add one day using the `add` method it will change the date directly to the first of the next month if you currently are the 31th.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime()` to get a timestamp and then `date` with the resulting timestamp, like so:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("12/15/2011"));
```